# How to call getCurrentFocus() in external class in Android(Maybe Context) instead of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, window

I want to call getCurrentFocus() out of activity or fragment to let the structure looks beautiful.But how can I call the method?Sometimes I use context as a parameter to achieve similar function.

Comment: kindly accept the answer so other can easily get idea @Marshall

Answer (score 26):

You can do this by using Activity, Create a class named **Utils** and put the following code in it.

```
public class Utils{
public static void hideKeyboard(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can simply call this method in any Activity to hide keyboard

```
Utils.hideKeyboard(Activity MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: @Marshall Please Accept answer if it worked for you? People up-voted this answer so it means it is working. Thanks

Comment: `@NonNull` before the parameter would be a nice touch to prevent a call with a `null` activity which would throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I just added the Null parameter check, Thanks for the suggestion, Appreciated

Comment: Is it possible to use it as not static method? I have activity instance in service object but I am not able to call activity.getCurrentFocus()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {

    val view = currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.windowToken,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
        )
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension function from a `Fragment`

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
activity?.let {
    val view: View? = it.currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm =
            context!!.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
        imm!!.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

}