# How to keep the softkeyboard hidden in a custom alertdialog?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have been trying to find a solution that works for my specific use case, but I have yet to find the proper setup. I have a custom `AlertDialog` with an `EditText`. I am handling the text input without the system keyboard, so having it pop up when I show the dialog on screen is an issue.

I have already looked at a number of different solutions, but none of them have worked for me. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609407/how-to-call-getcurrentfocus-in-external-class-in-androidmaybe-context-instea/28560201), this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@martinsuchen3557/android-force-hide-system-keyboard-while-retaining-edittexts-focus-9d3fd8dbed32), and [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard).

```java
public void showAlert() {
    alert.show();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // using this view to hide the keyboard causes a NPE
    View view = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getCurrentFocus();

    // I have also passed in a 0 for this one.
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ttsAlert.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    // This is the editText in the view
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

    // This is the rootView of the custom layout
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);

    editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
}
```

If anyone can determine what small detail (or large, obvious code block) I have missed to keep the keyboard from showing, I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: I should note, I need the cursor to remain visible. I have found a few more solutions that involve hiding the cursor, but that won't work for my use case.

Comment: Test your solution well with Samsung, Motorola, Sony, and LG phones. The former is known for _big f**k ups_ with the Keyboard/Layout engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more digging, I found the solution I needed for my use case. The keyboard does not appear, but the cursor stays.

```java
alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

The method is now simply this:

```java
public void showAlert() {
    alert.show();
    alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this solution works for Lenovo tablets. I do not have devices from other companies to test this with. Fortunately for my use case, this is all that matters.